# Messages.app only shows replies

Tags: macos, messages

Mavericks (10.9.5) Messages app is only showing what other people are typing, and not what *I* am typing! Has anyone else seen/fixed this?

Comment: You asked the same qusetion here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6567897  and got a respond! does it not work for you?

Comment: Hi Buscar, yes this solution worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Buscar noted above, I got an answer to my problem from a very helpful person on the Apple discussion board. [You can see the discussion here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6567897).

Somehow, this problem is related to permissions, and ACLs. The answer involved checking permissions from the command-line to see if there was a problem, and then resetting the permissions using either the command line, or using the Recovery partition on your Mac.

Use the following command to see if permissions/ACLs are incorrect:

```
find ~ $TMPDIR.. \( -flags +sappnd,schg,uappnd,uchg -o ! -user $UID -o ! -perm -600 \) 2>&- | wc -l
```

If you get a number other than 0 back, then there might be a problem. Use the following to repair permissions/ACLs (**make a backup first!**):

```
sudo find ~ $TMPDIR.. -exec chflags -h nouchg,nouappnd,noschg,nosappnd {} + -exec chown -h $UID {} + -exec chmod +rw {} + -exec chmod -h -N {} + -type d -exec chmod -h +x {} + 2>&-
```

Alternatively, you can 'Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs' outlined in [this Stackexchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-should-i-correct-the-owners-and-permissions-in-an-os-x-lion-user-folder).

I hope this helps someone else out there!