# Deleting and creating users with terminal in recovery mode?

Tags: terminal, user-account, macos

would anyone know how to delete and create user accounts in recovery mode? Precise steps would be awesome because im not too experienced with UNIX.

I already tried the userdel and useradd in urs\sbin folder.. "command not found", sudo or not.

I managed to bust up my OSX lion so it freezes in the grey apple start screen.
Steps I took to succeed in that was:

1.Renamed my user account
2.Removed all permissions from "everyone" from my homefolder

I've tried all the basic NVRAM/PRAM resettings, repairing disks and user permissions with disk utility and restarting in safe-mode without any luck.
The symptoms are not exactly the same but I thought to try this one trick from a post that I saw here, deleting the renamed user account and creating one back with the old name (though not with terminal here):

Last comment:
[How Should I Correct the Owners and Permissions in an OS X User Folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/how-should-i-correct-the-owners-and-permissions-in-an-os-x-lion-user-folder)