# Flawed user permissions: cannot save files or open programs

Tags: macos, permission, user-account, acl

I'm on OSX 10.9.1 and I changed settings on my user folder. As far as I can remember I "only" pressed `cmd + i` on the user folder and under access rights I chose `apply to all sub folders`. Don’t ask me why - I know I was being stupid and I won’t do it again .. promise!

So from what I understand that means I changed all files and folders inside of my user folder to belong to the root user and therefore don’t allow me to do any file operations for example copying files etc ..

What can I do to fix this?

- I’ve already used Disk Utility to repair permissions. But no luck. This is what it says. Sorry it’s in German: `ACL was found, but not expected in …`. For `Library/StartupItems` it also says `SUID-file …/ARDAgent` was changed and will not be repaired. Here's the details:

  ```
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/etc/apache2/users“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/etc/paths.d“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers“ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/MAS“ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/LaunchAgents“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/LaunchDaemons“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/PreferencePanes“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/ScriptingAdditions“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Library/StartupItems“Achtung: Die SUID-Datei „System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/ARDAgent“ wurde verändert und wird nicht repariert.
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/root/Library“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/root/Library/Preferences“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.stackshot.plist“Abweichende Zugriffsrechte für „usr/lib/ruby“, Soll-Wert: lrwxr-xr-x , Ist-Wert: drwxr-xr-x .
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „usr/lib/ruby“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „usr/libexec/cups/driver“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „Applications/.DS_Store“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/at/tabs“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/db/lockdown“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/root/Library/.localized“
  ACL wurde gefunden, aber nicht erwartet auf „private/var/root/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist“
  ```
- I also tried to “Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs” through the „Reset Password“ OSX Utility as suggested [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/). But no luck :(

**Here's some more infos:**

- Terminal ls -la on `/Users`folder:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x   5 root  admin   170 21 Dez  2013 .
  drwxr-xr-x  37 root  wheel  1326  5 Feb 10:12 ..
  -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     0 12 Sep  2013 .localized
  drwxrwxrwt  11 root  wheel   374 29 Dez 12:57 Shared
  drwxr-xr-x+ 69 root  admin  2346 10 Feb 11:06 macdaddy
  ```
- Terminal ls -l on `/Users/macdaddy/` (my user) folder:

  ```
  drwxr-xr-x+   4 root  admin   136 24 Aug 22:26 Applications
  drwxr-xr-x+  69 root  admin  2346 10 Feb 09:58 Desktop
  drwxr-xr-x+  10 root  admin   340  3 Jul  2014 Documents
  drwxr-xr-x+  25 root  admin   850  9 Feb 23:50 Downloads
  drwxr-xr-x@  15 root  admin   510  5 Feb 10:12 Dropbox
  drwxr-xr-x+  72 root  admin  2448  1 Feb 20:17 Library
  drwxr-xr-x+  10 root  admin   340 14 Jan 16:07 Movies
  drwxr-xr-x@  16 root  admin   544  8 Feb 18:06 Music
  drwxr-xr-x+  11 root  admin   374  5 Feb 18:21 PhpstormProjects
  drwxr-xr-x+ 119 root  admin  4046 10 Feb 00:40 Pictures
  drwxr-xr-x+   5 root  admin   170  7 Feb  2011 Public
  drwxr-xr-x+   6 root  admin   204 27 Mär  2014 Sites
  drwxr-xr-x+   8 root  admin   272  1 Dez 18:01 VirtualBox VMs
  drwxr-xr-x+   2 root  admin    68 29 Mai  2014 dumps
  ```

Am I right that the user should not be root, but macdaddy here? Also the `+` and `@` signs look uncommon to me.

So my question is: **How can I fix my problem so that the permissions are reverted back to their prior state. Or at least I want to be able to work as I did before.**

I found this solution:
[Resetting user permissions to their default mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31964/resetting-user-permissions-to-their-default-mode)
, in which first all ACL permissions are being removed, then all permissions being equalized with `chmod`. Now before trying it out I wanted to ask here if this method is advisable or if there is any other way of fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk Utility doesn't check permissions for user home folders. To do this on systems later than 10.6 you will need to boot into recovery mode (or boot from a USB installer) and go to **Utilities > Terminal**, then type `resetpassword`. Here you will find the option to reset permissions for a specific user's home folder.

Alternatively you can reset home folder permissions with **Onyx**, free from Titanium Software.

Comment: as mentioned above I already “Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs” through the „Reset Password“ OSX Utility. Will have a look at Onyx though

Comment: I tried to download **Onyx**, but Safari pops an error that there's not enough memory on the disk to download Onyx. That's surely not the case as I have over 82GB of free disk space. 
HELP! :(

Comment: Can you create a new user account (with admin privileges)? If so you can install and run Onyx there, it has the option in preferences to run commands on the current account or all accounts - you will want to select the "all accounts" option. Hopefully this will do the trick...

Comment: I managed to download Onyx with wget as sudo from the Terminal. But now I don't know what to do with the program. How can it help me?

Comment: Maintenance > Permissions > Reset home folder permissions and ACLs

Comment: BTW, "SUID-file …/ARDAgent was changed and will not be repaired" - this is completely normal behaviour when checking permissions and is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. But I think it will do the same as here (http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/), which I have already tried as stated above ..

Comment: With Onyx I did "reset home folder permissions and acl", but without any success. After restart I still can't even copy a file on my desktop.

Comment: As above, can you create a new user account from System Preferences?

Comment: Try chown -R (your username) /Users/(username) - e.g. chown -R frank /Users/frank - you may want to run sudo -i first to run the command as root

Comment: The `chown` command fixed it! Thanks man really appreciate it. Seems like I changed all the files to belong to root  recursively and the chown command reset it to my user :)